# WebApi and Api Key Validation location

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a public REST API.  Clients that are registered will be given an API key to use the API, from their servers (not from a browser).  A single client can also have multiple keys, potentially for unique apps on their servers.  So I'm curious where people would validate the API Keys...

1. Use the Delegating Handler (usually for Authentication) and do the key look up.
2. Use Authorization Filters to see if the key is authorized.

For unauthorized, I want to return 400 - bad request OR 403 - forbidden (in the case the key suspended).

My first thought is that the key is for authorization to get access, and doesn't identify the app using the service.  But, doing the the key look up in the Delegating Handler allows me to short circuit more quickly (in the HTTP Message Handler) instead of in the Controller, where the Authorization Filters fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API key is a credential you validate, which is basically authentication. I believe message handler is a good place to authenticate and set the principal. Authorization filter which runs later in the pipeline can authorize, if the identity established earlier by the handler is allowed to make that call. I have implemented [hawk authentication](https://github.com/hueniverse/hawk), which uses shared key, in a message handler for [Thinktecture identity model](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.45). For more info  on using ttidm and hawk with ASP.NET Web API, see [here](http://lbadri.wordpress.com/2013/07/04/hawk-authentication-for-asp-net-web-api-using-thinktecture-identitymodel-45/).

There are a couple of things to note with respect to message handlers. Message handlers run early in the web API pipeline but comparatively later in the ASP.NET pipeline (assuming web hosting). The identity you establish in web API handler is applicable to only web API and IIS/ASP.NET knows nothing about it. If you know you will only web host, an `HttpModule` will be a better place.

In Web API 2, there is an AuthenticationFilter. I don't know more details on this but heard Dominick Baier mentioning this in NDC 2013. Another candidate is the OWIN middleware, if you plan to use OWIN.